# Android CTS tests timing out

Tags: android

I've been trying to use the Android CTS package on a copy of Android built from source but I'm having trouble where a large number of tests time out and then fail.

I'm build from the tag android-cts-verifier-4.0.3_r1.  I can install the image on my test device and it seems to work fine.  From that point I've run CTS wirelessly and with USB, getting similar results (except that some network tests fail when connecting wirelessly unsurprisingly).  I've tried both eng and userdebug builds and I've followed all the steps in the CTS instructions (the pdf file, not the web page).

The biggest problem seems to be in the package android.media.  I get results such as:

```
-- testLocalVideo_3gp_H263_176x144_300kbps_12fps_AAC_Mono_24kbps_11025Hz    
fail

Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Failed to receive adb shell test output within 600000 ms. Test may have timed out, or adb connection to device became unresponsive'. Check device logcat for details
```

where the corresponding logcat entry is a long string of:

```
I/AwesomePlayer(   93): after SEEK_VIDEO_ONLY we're late by 387.07 secs
I/AwesomePlayer(   93): we're much too late (387.09 secs), video skipping ahead
```

It isn't always exactly the same videos that fail, it isn't all the videos that fail, and it actually isn't only android.media that has the problem (I've seen it in the package android.holo as well).

With a 10 minute timeout for relatively short tests, this increases my testing time by several hours along with the fact that failing tests worry me (since ultimately I'm hoping to test modified android builds with CTS).

Has anyone seen something similar, and if so, is there some solution?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What is your test device?

Comment: I'm no longer working on any of that stuff, but when I was, my main test devices were a Motorola Xoom and a Samsung Galaxy Nexus.  I had other devices, but those were always being compared to the two main ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually figured out how to solve this problem so I'm answering myself.

If I build Android with the binaries extracted from an actual device, using script

```
device/$MANUFACTURER/$DEVICE/extract-files.sh
```

the various media tests do not time out.  I've tested this on both the Motorola Xoom (wingray) and the Samsung Galaxy Nexus (maguro).  So it seems that this is a driver issue of some kind.

This also makes it seems that there is no way to make this work for the emulator (but since the emulator has enough other problems of its own, it might be understandable).